# Capture values before NA in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as below. I am trying to capture value that is coming before all NA values. For example,
Below dataframe has on and off NA values. But I Need to capture a value that is 77 because, after this value, all are NA and there is no value between. Can anyone help me with the logic to capture this?

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,NA,3,NA,NA,6,8,3,2,5,6,77,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

but if it ends with non NA

asd <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,NA,3,NA,NA,6,8,3,2,5,6,77,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,65,56))

```
Here it should capture 56 since it is the last value and no NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this function

```
library(xts)
last_before_na <- function(x){
  if (!is.na(last(x))){
    y = as.numeric(last(x))
    return(c(y, last(which(x == y))))
  } else {
    y = last(na.omit(x[!is.na(x)]))
    return(c(y,last(which(x == y))))
    
  }
  
}



asd <- data.frame(a = c(NA,1,2,NA,3,NA,NA,6,8,3,2,5,6,77,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
last_before_na(asd)

[1] 77 14

asd <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,NA,3,NA,NA,6,8,3,2,5,6,77,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,65,56))
last_before_na(asd)

[1] 56 22
```

## one more 77

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c(NA,1,2,NA,3,NA,NA,6,8,3,2,5,77,77,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
last_before_na(asd)
[1] 77 14
```

But I think it's better..

```
xts::last(na.omit(asd))
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry it does not end. I have edited my question

Comment: @manup I edit the code.

Comment: One last question, Can we find which index(row number) this value is coming? Here it is 13 (the place where 77 is located)

Comment: @manup I edit the function.

Comment: :)I did this actually. But what if there are 2 times 77 values ???? Which index would it take? :)

Comment: @manup I didn't notice about that, but this time, `last` will help as again :D. I edit the function.

Answer (score 1):

In base R

```r
with(asd1, tail(na.omit(a), 1))
#[1] 77
with(asd2, tail(na.omit(a), 1))
#[1] 56
```

### Sample data

```r
asd1 <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,NA,3,NA,NA,6,8,3,2,5,6,77,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
asd2 <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,NA,3,NA,NA,6,8,3,2,5,6,77,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,65,56))
```